# Iterating through a ruby nested hash with nils?

Tags: ruby, hash, error-handling, hash-of-hashes

**Let say I'm getting back a JSON nested hash (or array of hashes) from an API**

```
@example = {"results" = > {{"poop" => "shoop"},{"foo" => {"shizz" => "fizz", "nizzle"=>"bizzle"}}}
```

YAML markup for the nested hash above

```
  - poop: shoop
  - foo:
    shizz: fizz
    nizzle: bizzle
```

Now lets go make a db entry with ActiveRecord from the hash. This works fine.

```
Thing.create!(:poop  => @example["results"]["poop"],
                :shizz => @example["results"]["foo"]["shizz"],
                :nizzle=> @example["results"]["foo"]["nizzle"])
```

**But what if 'foo' is empty or nil?** For example, if an API result has a "person" hash with "first name","last name" #  etc, the "person" hash will usually be empty if there is no data, which means the hashes inside it don't exist.

```
@example = {"results" = > {{"poop" => "shoop"},{"foo" => nil }}

  Thing.create!(:poop  => @example["results"]["poop"],
                :shizz => @example["results"]["foo"]["shizz"],
                :nizzle=> @example["results"]["foo"]["nizzle"])

  NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it! 
  You might have expected an instance of Array. 
  The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
```

**What's the best way to handle this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came accross a `nil` sensitive `Hash#get` method a while back.

```
class Hash
  def get(key, default=nil)
    key.split(".").inject(self){|memo, key_part| memo[key_part] if memo.is_a?(Hash)} || default
  end
end

h = { 'a' => { 'b' => { 'c' => 1 }}}
puts h.get "a.b.c"    #=> 1
puts h.get "a.b.c.d"  #=> nil
puts h.get "not.here" #=> nil
```

It's pretty handy for this sort of JSON drilling.

Otherwise you have to do stuff like this:

```
h['a'] && h['a']['b'] && h['a']['b']['c']
```

And that just sucks.

Comment: indeed very interesting, how 'exhaust' the memo hash

Comment: slick - that will come in handy

Comment: So would I make a custom class that extends the system 'Hash' class, or would I monkey patch this 'get' method into 'Hash'?

Comment: This is rarely any major harm done by extending classes provided by the standard library.  I wouldn't make a gem depend on this method or anything, but its fine to use in your own app.  So just roll it into `Hash` and have fun doing `{'a' => 1}.get 'a'`

Answer (score 3):

Ruby 2.3.0 introduced [a new method called `dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-dig) on both `Hash` and `Array` that solves this problem entirely.

```
value = hash.dig(:a, :b)
```

It returns `nil` if the key is missing at any level.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using rails (not sure if it's in ruby 1.9):

```
h = {"a"=>1}
h.try(:[],"a") #1
h.try(:[],"b") #nil

h2 = {"c"=>{"d"=>1}}
h2.try(:[],"c").try(:[],"d")   #1
h2.try(:[],"a").try(:[],"foo") #nil
```

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb, line 28
def try(*a, &b)
  if a.empty? && block_given?
    yield self
  else
    __send__(*a, &b)
  end
end
```

Comment: I like this solution for Rails apps, but I'm looking for a more low-level, pure Ruby solution. I will try this, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I went ahead and started passing all Hash results into a [Hashie Mash](https://github.com/intridea/hashie#mash). That way they behave like Ruby objects and respond to nils like a champ!